# Move Gmail subaccount to new Gmail account

Tags: gmail, imap, pop3, gmail-imap, migrate-data

I have an email that imports via POP3 mail from a server but doesn't a leave a copy in the server. Now I need to import all the mails I got via that POP3 to a new Gmail account, I have some personal email that I don't want copied to the new mail, any way to do this?

I found that importing with IMAP would work but I think that would import all of the mail, not only the ones marked as retrieved via POP3. Also tried to import from the POP3 server using the new Gmail account and got nothing (most likely because I didn't marked to save mails to server when setting the previous POP3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google support suggests that if you're migrating from one Gmail/Google Apps account to a different Gmail/Google Apps account, just use POP3 between them. ([Directions here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?rd=1))

However, you want to only copy/move some of the messages.

I would use a third-party email client that can connect to Gmail via IMAP. (Thunderbird would probably be my choice.)

Connect to both accounts with IMAP. (Thunderbird does will managing multiple accounts.) Then copy/move the messages you want from the one account to the other.

Note that folders in Thunderbird correspond to tags in GMail and thus have some quirks. See [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43421/how-to-transfer-specific-e-mails-between-gmail-account-and-google-apps/67813#67813) for a more in-depth explanation and guidance on moving messages out from folders.

Comment: Will I have to manually copy each? Or does it handle folders/tagged messages?

Comment: It shouldn't be _too_ bad. From what I recall, you should be able to drag-drop whole "folders".